# Is it possible to use CSS3 transition to animate the value of a meter-tag?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible with css only to animate the visual change to a meter / progress-tag if the value changed?

Somthing like this

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
```

Or

```
-webkit-transition: meter-value 1s linear;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, CSS is meant only to change the *presentation* of a page, while the value is part of the page's *content*, and must be specified either directly in HTML or manipulated via JavaScript.

**Edit:** I slightly misunderstood your question, but the answer remains the same. CSS transitions are meant to animate CSS properties only, and it isn't possible to access an element's value from CSS.

Comment: This is about presentation, the question is if it's possible to animate when the value changes — with CSS3 it's possible to animate an element by changing its class with Javascript for example

Answer (score 14):

Yes it is perfectly possible, because WebKit uses Shadow DOM to materialize the meter element instead of using default system one (so the meter ans progress bar can be styled). You can figure this as an hidden content inside the meter element :

```
<div pseudo="-webkit-meter-inner-element">
    <div pseudo="-webkit-meter-bar">
        <div pseudo="-webkit-meter-optimum-value" style="width: 46%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you change the value of your meter, WebKit will change the width of the last div. So with :

```
meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value, meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value, meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value {
    transition: 1s width;
}
```

You can animate your meter.

Comment: Thanks, never too late. If only I had known this three years ago.

Comment: This should probably be updated to the correct answer.

Comment: When I wrote this, meter / progress elements were webkit-only.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible, because this property is not supported as `transition-property`. Proof: [**w3.org**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#properties-from-css-)